# how to run mongod as daemon with replica configurations?

Tags: mongodb, centos, replication

I use to run the mongodb service with the command ( in CentOS)
  sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
in mongod.conf file replica set information are there.
Now when my system is rebooted, I want automatically this service to run.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Is your query resolved? Did you try the suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` script is executed by the init command at boot time or when changing runlevels. Any command that you want to run after reboot can be added in this file. Just add the command at the end of the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`

You should also check the section `Using a Basic Init Script` in the following link: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mongodb/use-mongodb-to-store-application-data-on-centos-5/